# Why doesn't Android Studio accept my imported team settings?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm using Android Studio on a new Mac and have tried a few times now to add my team's settings via import (`File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Import Settings`), but each time AS restarts, it opens the Setup Wizard and then reverts back to the default settings. My team members have all recently gotten new Macs as well and all use the team settings without issue. I've searched around, but haven't found any suggestions for how to get around this issue or why this may be happening.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using Mac read this it could help:
[export-import-settings](https://www.iditect.com/guide/android/export-import-settings.html)

I recommend checking if everything is up to date too.